# Objective-C in Mono

Tags: objective-c, macos, directx, webcam, monomac

I have a .NET application, which I want to port to OSX. Up to now I used a DirectShow DLL for WebCam handling. Can I use an Objective-C DLL for Mono? How? I'm a newbie on Mac. Is there an existing (WebCam handling) solution for this? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the QTKit framework to do this, in particular you can use the QTCaptureView as a reusable NSView that you can embed in an existing window or in an application to do the actual video capturing.

I have just added support for capturing to the MonoMac bindings a few minutes ago after I saw your question, so you will need to do a little bit of work.

Steps:

1. Install Mono, MonoDevelop and the MonoMac addin as described here: http://mono-project.com/MonoMac
2. Download the latest sources for MonoMac and MacCore from Github: http://github.com/mono/maccore and http://github.com/mono/monomac
3. Update the MonoMac.dll to the latest version, by going into the monomac/src directory and typing "make update"

At this point you should be able to use the QTCaptureView in your MonoMac applications like any other NSView.   A tutorial showing the use of the API in Objective-C is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155-CH8-SW1

You can just use the equivalent versions in C#

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "an object-c dll for Mono".

Your absolute best approach is to learn the platform you're targeting and port only the logic and general architecture.

To access cameras, microphones, line-ins, etc. on Mac OS X, use QTKit (Quicktime Kit). It's mind-numbingly simple to set up a web cam view, record to files, grab frames, etc. It's built in and designed to make this sort of thing mostly drag-and-drop for developers.

Comment: No. .NET, DLLs, etc. are Windows technology / Windows API. Again: you need to learn the platform you're targeting. There's no way around that. The proper Mac high-level API for interfacing with web cams is QTKit. Lower level is the full QuickTime framework.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What I mean: I want a dll what is written in object-c, and it uses the OSX's API (for WebCam handling), and my Mono program (what is the clone of .NET on OSX) uses it. Up this time I did this with DirectX/Windows+.NET, and now I want QuictTime/OSX+Mono.

Comment: Sorry, that was my misunderstanding. From the MonoMac site: "Unlike MonoTouch, MonoMac is not a complete binding for all of the Cocoa APIs..." The list does not include QTKit or QuickTime. http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac

Comment: Ran out of room. I urge you not to port. It's likely it would be easier than you imagined to write the app natively using the existing API. Your more discerning Mac user base will appreciate a Mac app that looks and behaves like a Mac app.

Answer (score 0):

MonoMac is just one alternative. There are Monobjc, CocoSharp, NObjective, MObjc / MCocoa and ObjC# (I cannot choose between them). Theese are all "bridges" between Mono and Cocoa, what mean you can use Cocoa API in Mono application. But I don't want to use the API directly. I just want a dinamically linked library, which provide me some function for WebCam handling (as I said, I did this up to this time on Windows). In other words: I need a wrapper in Mono for QTKit.

PS: If I rewrite the application in object-c that means several months, and double work in the future when the application will grow. I love object-c but I hate to work unnecessary.

Comment: 2 things.  1) Use the same user more than once!  2) Edit your questions, do not answer with a comment.

Comment: MonoMac has bindings to QTKit which will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted code in XCode, and when I tried to port to Monodevelop, several classes are missing, eg. QTCaputureSession, QTCaputreDeviceInput, CVimagebuffer.
(Sorry, I cannot edit my previous messages, this is another account.)